# How to encrypt existing mariadb tables in CentOS?

Tags: mysql, linux, encryption, centos, mariadb

I am configuring data at rest encryption for my MariaDB instance. I want to encrypt all tablespaces automatically. I have configured MariaDB encryption options in my options file and all new tables are encrypted. However, existing tables are not encrypted. I can manually encrypt them using this command:

```
ALTER TABLE users ENCRYPTED=YES;
```

Here is what I have added to my options file:

```
plugin_load_add=file_key_management
file_key_management_filename=/mnt/mariadb_databases/mysql/encryption/keyfile.enc
    file_key_management_filekey=FILE:/mnt/mariadb_databases/mysql/encryption/.keyfile.key
    file_key_management_encryption_algorithm=aes_ctr
    innodb_default_encryption_key_id=3
    innodb_encrypt_tables=FORCE
    innodb_encrypt_log=ON
    innodb_encryption_threads=1
    encrypt_tmp_files=ON
    innodb_encryption_rotate_key_age=1
```

I used this command to check which tables are encrypted:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.INNODB_TABLESPACES_ENCRYPTION;
```

OS: CentOS 7

MariaDB version: 10.4.6 (was upgraded from 5.5 originally through each subsequent version)

Options file: /etc/my.cnf

How can I have all existing tables get encrypted automatically? I thought the innodb_encrypt_tables=FORCE option would do it but it isn’t working as expected and I don’t want to run the ALTER TABLE statement for all existing tables.

Answer (score 0):

`innodb_encrypted_tables=FORCE` means, that you can't create new tables which are unencrypted, so `CREATE TABLE ... ENCRYPTED=NO` will fail. It doesn't mean, that all tables will automatically converted to encrypted tables (and which might take a long time).

So in case you want to convert all your tables you have to do it manually (or by writing some small script).